# Proper syntax for linking a separatae CSS document named "stylesheet" to an html page

Tags: html, css

What is the proper syntax for linking a separate CSS document named "stylesheet" to an html page, especially when both documents live in the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
```

and place it in your `head`.